# Is there a way to produce a custom iOS keyboard like Grammarly's without writing the whole keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, grammarly

Title says it all, did grammarly really build all of their iOS keyboard functionality by themselves? or are there shortcuts by extending the default keyboard?

Comment: Since Apple's APIs do not provide any access to modify the default keyboard then one must assume all custom keyboards are being written in full from scratch. Though I'd love to be proven wrong on this. :)